# Jobs with both Remote tag and city/state name

Tags: job-search, job-description, telecommute, remote-work, location

My question is what is the meaning when you see a job with both remote and state/city name tag. For example here is a sample job.

[image: Sample Job SS]

As you can see it says both Antwerp Metropolitan Area and Remote. What that means? Is this job remote for anywhere in the world or just remote for the residents of Antwerp Metropolitan Area?

Comment: I've edited your post a little. Please do not use abbreviations in general, and specifically the abbreviation ["SS"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_(disambiguation)). it's super ambiguous and it's "default" guess is not very favorable.

Comment: @nvoigt haha right. Would you please comment what you think about the question I asked.

Comment: Generally tags are intended to allow potential candidates to make a first selection of relevant jobs, but no more than that. The actual **job description is leading**. If that description is not clear on the subject of working remotely, then simply ask the listed contact for clarification. Even if a company allows you to work 100% remote  and will never need to see you on-premise a **geographic area is relevant** when their expectation is that you **align with regular local business hours**  to collaborate and attend video conferences. Even with global multinationals a budget/team can be local

Answer (score 3):

In Belgium it is quite normal to find partly remote jobs, where you get 2-3 days of WFH and the other days you have to be in the office. In this case the office is located in Antwerp Metropolitan Area.

Another possibility is that the job is fully remote, but the platform advertising it requires them to still provide a location.

Even if the latter is the case, the job still may only be open to residents of the country where the company is located, for whatever reason.

The only way of knowing for sure would be to apply or at least contact them about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So its better to apply for these jobs if you are not from the mentioned country/state/area since these jobs could be fully remote as well.

Comment: Edited to include a response to your comment.

Comment: It's also very possible many job posting nowadays will have that in their title/description, cause all of the sudden lot of employers who were not into it seem to now understand how valuable it is... or anyway are forced to do so